# Removing attributes from HTML tags

Tags: php, python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [php: how can I remove attributes from an html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770219/php-how-can-i-remove-attributes-from-an-html-tag)
>   [How do I iterate over the HTML attributes of a Beautiful Soup element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822571/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-html-attributes-of-a-beautiful-soup-element)

I have some HTML like the following:

```
<div class="foo">
  <p id="first">Hello, world!</p>
  <p id="second">Stack Overflow</p>
</div>
```

And it needs to come back as this:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
  <p>Stack Overflow</p>
</div>
```

I'd prefer a Python solution, as I'm already using BeautifulSoup in the program it needs to be used in. However, I'm open to PHP if that's a better solution. I don't think a sed regular expression would be enough, especially with the possible future use of the < symbol in the text (I don't control the input).

Comment: and [how-do-i-iterate-over-the-html-attributes-of-a-beautiful-soup-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822571/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-html-attributes-of-a-beautiful-soup-element) and [python-how-to-search-and-correct-html-tags-and-attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360968/python-how-to-search-and-correct-html-tags-and-attributes) and [python-extracting-html-tag-attributes-without-regular-expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141431/python-extracting-html-tag-attributes-without-regular-expressions)

Comment: What have you tried so far? (Please don't try using regular expressions, particularly if you already know how to us an HTML parser like Beautiful Soup).

Comment: I've tried using a regular expression but it's long and goes wrong somewhere.

Comment: I would still recommend using XSLT for this problem! Identity template all the way.
Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119923/removing-styling-from-html/7119975#7119975

Answer (score 0):

this works also with sed,
<([a-zA-Z!]+)[^>]+>
then just replace by the first group like,
<\1>

Answer (score 0):

This is easily possible in Python by using **[Lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3)**.

First install **[Lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3)** and try the following code:

```
from lxml.html import tostring, fromstring

html = '''
<div class="foo">
  <p id="first">Hello, world!</p>
  <p id="second">Stack Overflow</p>
</div>'''

htmlElement = fromstring(html)
for element in htmlElement.cssselect(''):
    for key in element.keys():
        element.attrib.pop(key)

result = tostring(htmlElement)

print result
```